# How to show/hide loading spinner in addon sidebar while Google Picker dialog is opened/closed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-picker

I followed this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs and I can open a Google Picker after clicking a button inside my addon sidebar.

I want to do 2 things for better UX for my users:

- The first thing is when the Google Picker is open, I want to show a loading spinner inside my addon sidebar (to prevent users from interacting with the sidebar), so that users can only interact with the Google Picker until it's closed
- After users choose a document or directly close the Google Picker, the loading spinner in the addon sidebar will also be disappeared **immediately** (we shouldn't reload the sidebar), and users can interact with the addon sidebar normally

> Please note: the loading indicator is **inside** the addon sidebar
> (not inside the picker dialog)

What I have done is:

I have 2 files:

1. **sidebar.html**
2. **picker.html**

Both these html files contain html, css, js that you need to run each of them.

Inside the `sidebar.html`, when I need to open the Picker, I will call:

```
function openPicker() {
  // Show spinner here
  showSpinner()

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function() { console.log('ok') })
    .showPicker()
}
```

Above function will call this showPicker() function in `Code.gs`:

```
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('picker.html')
    .setWidth(800)
    .setHeight(600)
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file')
}
```

Inside the `picker.html`, I have a callback:

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
    var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION]
    if (action === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0]
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID]
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL]
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME]
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a><br>ID: ' + id
    } else if (action === google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        google.script.host.close()
    }

    // This is a good place to hide the spinner, 
    // but this is picker.html, so it can not control code in sidebar.html to hide the spinner
}
```

The problem here is, the `sidebar.html` can only know when to show the spinner, not when to close it.

The logic to detect when we should close the spinner lies in the picker.html itself (only the picker knows when the user has selected a document or canceled the picker).

And I don't know how to pass that logic to the `sidebar.html` so that it can run `hideSpinner()` somewhere inside `sidebar.html`.